# How to record LAN computer screen on centos/ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, centos

we have a office with 40 computers and some computers have ubuntu and some computers have windows 8/7 installed and i want to configure a ubuntu/centos server here for networking and i want to record screens of all my LAN computers so anyone can help me which tool i should use and for better and easy to configure which server platform i should select whether ubuntu or centos ?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd go with vncservers on all the machines you want to record from and [vnc2flv](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/vnc2flv/index.html) running on the server. You're going to need lots of storage though (reducing the frame rate will help), and a way of periodically stopping and restarting flvrec to write to incremental files.